# WiX Heat Pre-build Error

Tags: wix

I have a WiX installer that was working fine, but it's been a few months since I worked on it... so, I am not attempting to build the installer (on a reconfigured machine) and now it fails to build every time.  I've tried to simplify everything to isolate where it's failing, but I still can't seem to figure out why.  Essentially, it looks like it's failing at the pre-build process.  I had a length Pre-build Event command, but I've simplified it to the bare essentials.  Here's my command:

```
call “$(WIX)bin\heat.exe” dir "$(SolutionDir)MyProj\bin\Release" -out “$(ProjectDir)MyFiles.wxs”
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
call “C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\heat.exe” dir "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\GitHub\MyProj\bin\Release" -out “C:\Users\MyName\Documents\GitHub\MyProj\Installer\MyFiles.wxs”
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

The code appears to exit with code 1, which seems to suggest that it's failing to locate a filename or path... however, I've checked the paths that are printed in the output log and the heat.exe application does exists under the C:\Program Files (x86) directory.  The directory (dir) it's trying to harvest is properly defined and the output location is as well.  So, does anyone know why this is failing?

**Update**

What's incredibly strange is that the pre-build event command seems to fail even when I simplify the command to try to simply call the heat.exe application (with no other parameters). I tried changing my pre-build event to the following:

```
call “C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\heat.exe”
```

As you can see from the attached image, the heat.exe application is indeed located in the directory specified in the build command. Yet, I still get an error saying that the MSBuild failed and exited with code 1.  If I check the output log, it says that the, "filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".  However, I can say that this installer was working properly a few months ago with no changes to the build events... so I really don't know why it wouldn't work now, except that I had to reconfigure my machine and reinstall Windows 10 recently.  I downloaded and installed the latest WiX toolset, and would assume that would be everything that is needed.  But, this error persists.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really dumb but I believe you need to put a `\` at the end of your dir IIRC. I think I ran into the same issue at one point. The error is not particularly helpful.

```
call "$(WIX)bin\heat.exe" dir "$(SolutionDir)MyProj\bin\Release\" -out "$(ProjectDir)MyFiles.wxs"
```

(I think I was remembering backwards and you need to NOT have the trailing \ in the dir.. sorry)

---

Just in case you can't get the pre-build event to work, you can also call heat like this (requires editing the wixproj file)

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(WIX)bin\heat.exe&quot; dir &quot;$(SolutionDir)MyProj\bin\Release&quot; -out &quot;$(ProjectDir)MyFiles.wxs&quot;"/>
</Target>
```

This is how I call heat in some of the installers I've authored. If this also doesn't work I'm out of ideas for why this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately still doesn't seem to fix the problem on my machine.

Comment: What's also odd is that the pre-build event fails if I simplify the command to simply try to launch the heat.exe application.  For example, if I just use: call “$(WIX)bin\heat.exe” then I still get the same error as above.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755654/build-events-not-honoring-multiple-command-line-arguments you should try `call “$(WIX)bin\heat.exe” dir "$(SolutionDir)MyProj\bin\Release\ " -out “$(ProjectDir)MyFiles.wxs”` (space after "Release\" because the \ was escaping the ") see if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately adding the space and backslash still didn't resolve the issue.  Again, what's completely odd is that even if I simplify the pre-build event to simply try to launch the heat.exe, it still fails.  I've updated my question to show what I mean.

Comment: So, I really don't know why... but your solution about adding the <Exec> command inside the wixproj file worked when the pre-build event command would not.  I really don't know why this would be the case, but at least now it's building again.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: `<Target Name="BeforeBuild" />` should be `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">`.

Answer (score 2):

I know its a little old question but I've faced the issue and spent hours to notice different qoutes here: `“$(WIX)bin\heat.exe”`. Replace with straight ones `"$(WIX)bin\heat.exe"` and enjoy.